# Data Reactivity On Post Request Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

Im having issues with my data not reacting correctly when a new object is added to the array of data. I am currently looping through an array of engagements that belong to a client like this

```
<div class="row mx-2 px-2 justify-content-between" v-if="!engagementLoaded">
            <div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm col-lg-5 col-md-3 p-0" v-for="(engagement, index) in engagement" :key="index">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between card-header">
                    <h3 class="m-0 text-muted">{{ index + 1 }}</h3>
                    <h5 class="align-self-center m-0"><span>Return Type: </span> {{ engagement.return_type }} </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body text-left p-0 my-1">
                    <h5 class="p-4"><span>Year: </span> {{ engagement.year }} </h5>
                    <hr class="my-1">
                    <h5 class="p-4"><span>Assigned To: </span> {{ engagement.assigned_to }} </h5>
                    <hr class="my-1">
                    <h5 class="p-4"><span>Status: </span> {{ engagement.status}} </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <router-link to="#" class="btn">View</router-link>
                    <router-link to="#" class="btn">Edit</router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Everything works fine until I add a new engagement to the array. My AddEngagement Component is seperate but this is the form and script for it.

```
<form @submit.prevent="addEngagement" class="d-flex-column justify-content-center">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control mb-3" id="type" v-model="engagement.return_type">
              <option v-for="type in types" :key="type.id" :value="type">{{ type }}</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Year" v-model="engagement.year">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Assign To" v-model="engagement.assigned_to">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Status" v-model="engagement.status">

            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-start">Create</button>
              <router-link v-bind:to="'/client/' +client.id+ '/engagements'" class="btn btn-secondary float-right">Dismiss</router-link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

This is the addEngagement Method for the form

```
methods: {
    addEngagement(e) {
      if(!this.engagement.return_type || !this.engagement.year ){
        return
      } else {
        this.$store.dispatch('addEngagement', {
          id: this.idForEngagement,
          client_id: this.client.id,
          return_type: this.engagement.return_type,
          year: this.engagement.year,
          assigned_to: this.engagement.assigned_to,
          status: this.engagement.status,
        })
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      this.engagement = "" 
      this.idForEngagement++
      this.$router.go(-1);
    },
  },
```

I think the issue is happening here but im not sure

```
this.$router.go(-1);
```

Ive tried this as well

this.$router.push({path: 'whatever route'})

and it did not change either

Somehow I need the parent component EngagementsList to react correctly to my newly added engagement that is submitted from the AddEngagement componenet if that makes sense..

Comment: What is the code in the vuex `addEngagement` action?

Comment: Is `this.engagement` an array? I ask because of this code `v-for="(engagement, index) in engagement"`.

Comment: @DecadeMoon yes it is an array

Comment: Then why are you doing `this.engagement.return_type` if `this.engagement` is an array?

Comment: @DecadeMoon maybe the confusion is that i am saying that for the each client there is an array of enagagements and in my vuex i have it described as `engagement: []` that the v-for loop is iterating over... but for submitting an engagement that belongs to a client, it is an object, which is why i have it described as this.engagement.whatever in my addEngagement method if that is what you are asking about?..

Comment: Oh they’re from separate components, otherwise the `engagement` property would conflict.

Comment: @DecadeMoon so are you saying that my `engagement: []` should be defined as something else so it does not cause conflict?

Comment: I mean you can’t have an `engagement` data property *and* a Vuex mapped `engagement` defined in the same component (which is what I thought was the case here). Also if `engagement` is an array then a better name would be `engagements` to avoid confusion.

Comment: @DecadeMoon, I am noticing that when i run the addEngagement method it changes my `engagement:[]` array to just the object of the newly added engagement..

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't see your code, I'm pretty certain I know the problem. You have an array but it's not reactive to the objects within. This is because Vue doesn't know to observe this array.

If you want your array to be reactive, use `Vue.set` from within your `store model`.

```
Vue.set(this/state, 'array_name', Array<Of objects>)
```

This will make sure vue watches for changes within the Array.

For your use case, you will need to append the engagement object to the existing array and then use that array:

```
const engagements = state.engagements

engagements.push(engagement)

Vue.set(state, 'engagements', engagements)
```

Comment: would the Vue.set bet in the getter?

Comment: @TJWeems No, it would be inside of the Mutation.

Comment: would it look something like this? `getClientEngagement(state, engagement) { state.engagement = Vue.set(engagement, 'engagement', what goes here?)}`

Comment: do i need to define engagements.push(engagement)? the (engagement) is giving me an "is not defined" alarm when I am viewing my ClientEngagements component....

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for the addEngagement in the Vuex

```
addEngagement(context, engagement) {
      axios.post(('/engagements'), {
        client_id: engagement.client_id,
        return_type: engagement.return_type,
        year: engagement.year,
        assigned_to: engagement.assigned_to,
        status: engagement.status,
        done: false
      })
      .then(response => {
        context.commit('getClientEngagement', response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

So i've tried different configurations of this. I changed my state description that the v-for is iterating to clientengagements

engagement now equals clientengagements

here is the mutation currently

```
getClientEngagements(state, engagement, clientengagements) {
      state.clientengagements = clientengagements
      clientengagements.push(engagement)
      Vue.set(state, 'clientengagements', clientengagements)
    },
```

Which is not working. Ive also tried

```
getClientEngagements(state, clientengagements) {
      state.clientengagements = clientengagements
      clientengagements.push(engagement)
      Vue.set(state, 'clientengagements', clientengagements)
    },
```

Which will tell me that "engagement" is not defined

If anyone is still able to help this is the Action

```
addEngagement(context, engagement) {
      axios.post(('/engagements'), {
        client_id: engagement.client_id,
        return_type: engagement.return_type,
        year: engagement.year,
        assigned_to: engagement.assigned_to,
        status: engagement.status,
        done: false
      })
      .then(response => {
        context.commit('getClientEngagements', response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
```

The response.data is mutating my clientengagements array to just a single object of the newly added engagement..

```
context.commit('getClientEngagements`, response.data)
```

Is commiting to this mutation

```
getClientEngagements(state, engagement, clientengagements) {
      state.clientengagements = clientengagements
      clientengagements.push(engagement)
      Vue.set(state, 'clientengagements', clientengagements)
    },
```